# JPA Transaction not commiting at the end of method

Tags: spring, hibernate, commit, flush, transactional

I have two methods:

```
1:
@Transactional
public Long add(Long clientId) {
    Contact contact = new Contact();
    contact.setClientId(clientId);
    contact.setValue('test@test.com');
    contact.setType('EMAIL');
    contact.setDateStart(new Date());
    // autowired repo
    return contactRepository.saveAndFlush(contact);
}

2:
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public void emailsValidator(Long clientId) {
    Specification<Client> spec = ClientSearchSpecification.getByClientIdWithActiveEmails(clientId);
    List<Client> clientList = clientRepository.findAll(spec);
}

SearchSpecification:
 public static Specification<Client> getByClientIdWithActiveEmails(Long clientId) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        query.distinct(true);
        Join<Client, Contact> clientContactJoin = (Join) root.fetch(Client_.contactList);
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get(AbstractEntity_.id), clientId));
        predicates.add(cb.equal(clientContaktJoin.get(Contakt_.type), 'EMAIL'));
        predicates.add(cb.lessThan(clientContaktJoin.get(Contakt_.dateStart), cb.currentTimestamp()));
        return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
    };
}
```

Main method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{clientId}/contact/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public void addContact(@PathVariable(value = "clientId") Long clientId) {
    contactService.add(clientId);
    errorValidationService.emailsValidator(clientId);
}
```

My db properties:

```
hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session: true
hibernate.connection.autocommit: true
org.hibernate.flushMode: COMMIT
```

The problem - DB doesn't contain new entity from step 1 while executing step 2. The object is commited only after all rest call finishes. How do I commit entity on step 1 so that I can select and join it in step 2?

Comment: Could you post the code that calls the two methods?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be committed to select your data (within the same transaction).

The problem here is that you've said step 2 needs to be `NOT_SUPPORTED, which implies that step 1 must commit before step 2 can see any of the data it inserted.

Try changing the propagation of step 1 to `REQUIRES_NEW` to ensure the commit occurs before you get to step 2.

Comment: Already tried that. Yes I can get all collection of beanList with loaded entities from step 1. But, I don't need all collection of entities, thats why I have my own Search Criteria, for ex: where cr_date > current_timestamp and type = 'something'. When I put any of @Transactions on the second method, Hibernate ignores my filtered Search Criteria and returns me all lnked data by that id.

Comment: Can you give some more information about how you call these 2 methods? Are they on the same object? What @Transactional annotation do you have on the caller of these methods? If possible post more of the code.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I was using two different @Transaction implementations in repository interface:

```
@Transactional
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Client>
```

I used:

```
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
```

I should've use:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
```

Which meant that settings for spring @Transaction were not applied and it couldn't commit itself at the end of the method, It did commits only at the end of the call.