# Spring JPA randomly suspends insert and goes in endless wait

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am calling a @Transactional method with a rollback on JPA for Exception.class. This function makes various inserts and selects successfully and also calls 2 SPs in sqlserver in different scenarios, just 1 case where.

**Problem**: I am booking an appointment and I have inserted in the main entity class of appointment along with sub tables where some appt details are put, there is another insert which maintains customer's health data which also gets added. After this an SP is called to check previous and current customer health data and execute some rules.
This works the first time.

Now when I try the same flow again, with a request where all the customer health data is removed, for some reason hibernate is stuck on the insert query, which further blocks the SP.
At this point any inserts/updates made in the transaction call are held waiting for entire transaction to get over.

Worst thing is the lock is being acquired on the entire table, so even if I retry all the subsequent retries fail and the blocked queue on SQL server keeps getting clogged. As soon as I kill the insert SPID everything goes back to normal, my request is complete with 200ok and all the data entries are perfect.

I have enabled detailed hibernate logs, which dont show the 2nd health id in the logs.

Any ideas will be helpful at this point.

I have tried to flush each repo which makes an insert and cross check if no other transaction is going in the background

interesting fact is this entire process was working seamlessly, until we tried BEGIN TRANSACTION one day on the SP, but it was reverted back and recompiled using

DBCC freeproccache

DBCC freesessioncache

DBCC freesystemcache ('All')

DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS

sp_recompile N'[dbo].[Customer_health_update]

Comment: Check if your initial transaction actually gets committed. You can run DBCC OPENTRAN in the database in question and read the message it outputs

Comment: Since I see it in sp_who2 active as suspended, am also able to see it in opentran.What I am unable to understand is why that would happen. its a simple insert query. hibernate logs, control did not stop
2023-03-01 17:03:33.795 [http-nio-8080-exec-2]: DEBUG o.h.SQL:92 - insert into customer_health (created_date, customer_id, health_changed_image_id, customer_health_image_upload_file_id, customer_health_sign_date, last_modified_date, customer_health_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2023-03-01 17:03:33.797 [http-nio-8080-exec-2]: DEBUG o.h.e.j.b.i.BatchingBatch:384 - Executing batch size: 1

Comment: it sounds like you aren't committing your tran. so the problem is probably related to how @Transactional stuff is handled by your code.  Does this link solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031008/jpa-transaction-not-commiting-at-the-end-of-method together with https://stackoverflow.com/a/37052156/13061224

Comment: Are you pointing me to the hibernate properties, I'm using the correct transactional lib and only on the method.

Comment: yeah, the props

Comment: Dont want to use these settings in enterprise app. exploring in the direction of propagation with isolation on transactional.